# React button OnHover change image inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onhover

I have a dynamic component that has three buttons with different images on each of them. I need to change the images on the buttons on hover. I used `onMouseOver` & `onMouseOut`. It seems to work but as soon as I hover on the button, it crashes with an error :

> `TypeError: btn.map is not a function`.

The possibility that there maybe some minor syntactical error, but I am unable to figure it out.

Here is the working snippet for the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wood-fzop7

Any help to rectify this is appreciated :)

Comment: do you need something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-wildflower-tmlv8)?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes. It worked. Can you please explain the changes to the function?

Comment: You are changing value of `btn` from an array to an object with `btn` property. That's why when state is updated, calling `.map()` on `btn` fails. You need to change the implementation of `changeHover` function so that it updates the state correctly. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-swartz-ocgnv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map the `btn` array and return new one with hovered element that will be used to change the image src :

```
 const changeHover = (val, bool) => {
    setBtn(btn.map((ele, id) => id === val  ? { ...ele, hovered: bool} : ele));
  };
```

Comment: There's no need to return a new object when `id === val` is false. You can just return `ele` as it is. `? { ...ele, hovered: bool} : ele`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing set state wrong you need to do like this:

```
const changeHover = (val, bool) => {
    console.log(val)
    setBtn((prevstate) => prevstate.map((ele, id) =>
    console.log("STATES", ele) || id === val
      ? { ...ele, hovered: bool }
      : { ...ele }
  ));
  };
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bush-w0zim